# Autorenewable In-app using MKstorekit?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in Iphone in  which i am trying to implement Autorenewable subscription using MKstorekit4.3.In which i noticed some server codes are there. Is it possible to use this without using the server component.So that by setting own server as nil and review access as nil.can anybody help me with exact mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you don't need to use your own server; MKStoreKit will use the verification URL on Apple's servers directly if you don't provide your own. But not recommended, for security reasons.